# buildozer(kivy,python) failed in copying generated apk to the home dir on docker virtual machine

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I tried to run buildozer in docker virtual machine to generate andorid app package(.apk).

After tried and filed sometimes, his Dockerfile(https://github.com/jedie/kivy-buildozer-docker) was determined to use to make my environment for my purpose.

However, in almost finished building, the error occured.

.apk was generated in success, but (I guessed) the error was caused the process that the .apk file copy from a working dir in generation into project_dir as below.

```
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/buildozer/kivy_hello_world/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
[INFO]:    # Copying APK to current directory
[INFO]:    # Found APK file: /home/buildozer/kivy_hello_world/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/kivy_hello_world/bin/HelloWorld-0.1-debug.apk
[DEBUG]:   -> running cp /home/buildozer/kivy_hello_world/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/kivy_hello_world/bin/HelloWorld-0.1-debug.apk ./
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 1058, in run_command
    self.target.run_commands(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 92, in run_commands
    func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 104, in cmd_debug
    self.buildozer.build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 212, in build
    self.target.build_package()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 817, in build_package
    copyfile(join(apk_dir, apk), join(self.buildozer.bin_dir, apk_dest))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 96, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/home/buildozer/kivy_hello_world/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/kivy_hello_world/build/outputs/apk/kivy_hello_world-debug.apk'
```

---

In the last sentence of `IOError`, a former path `/home/buildozer/kivy_hello_world/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/kivy_hello_world/` was exists.

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/home/buildozer/kivy_hello_world/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/kivy_hello_world/build/outputs/apk/kivy_hello_world-debug.apk'
```

However, latter path `build/outputs/apk/kivy_hello_world-debug.apk' was not exists.

What any idea to solve this? (This occured in python-for-android called from buildozer)
(Not solved: apt-get install binfmt-support)

- Spec.

  - Machine: MacBookPro, mac serria(10.12.6)
  - Docker: Docker version 18.01.0-ce, build 03596f5
  - Docker: docker-machine version 0.13.0, build 9ba6da9
  - Buildozer: v.034
  - python-for-android: fetched ver. by buildozer.

---

---

A little customized Dockerfile tried.

```
FROM ubuntu:17.10

MAINTAINER Jens Diemer "https://github.com/jedie/kivy-buildozer-docker"

# Update ubuntu:
RUN set -x \
    && apt-get update -qq \
    && apt-get -y full-upgrade \
    && apt-get autoremove \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# install needed packages for buildozer
# base is https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/blob/master/buildozer/tools/packer/scripts/additional-packages.sh
# But we need some more tools here ;)
RUN set -x \
    && dpkg --add-architecture i386 \
    && apt-get update -qq \
    && apt-get -y install \
        lib32stdc++6 lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 \
        build-essential \
        python-pip unzip curl \
    && apt-get -y install git openjdk-8-jdk --no-install-recommends zlib1g-dev \
    && apt-get autoremove \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# The buildozer VM used Cython v0.25 and buildozer v0.32
RUN set -x \
    && pip install -U pip \
    && pip install "cython<0.26" \
    && pip install "buildozer!=0.33" python-for-android pyOpenssl

ADD kivy_hello_world /home/buildozer/kivy_hello_world

RUN set -x \
    && adduser buildozer --disabled-password --disabled-login \
    && chown -R buildozer:buildozer /home/buildozer/

USER buildozer

# download all needed andorid dependencies:
RUN set -x \
    && cd /home/buildozer/kivy_hello_world \
    && buildozer -v android debug \
    && cd .. \
    && rm -rf kivy_hello_world

VOLUME /home/buildozer/

WORKDIR /home/buildozer/
```

---

Long log to have built. The a few rows in last shows error msg

```
Compiling /home/buildozer/kivy_hello_world/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/kivy_hello_world/private/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/saxutils.py ...
Compiling /home/buildozer/kivy_hello_world/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/kivy_hello_world/private/lib/python2.7/xml/sax/xmlreader.py ...
[INFO]:    Selecting java build tool:
[INFO]:    Detected highest available build tools version to be 19.1.0
[INFO]:        Building with ant, as the highest build-tools-version is only 19.1.0
[DEBUG]:   -> running ant debug
[DEBUG]:    Buildfile: /home/buildozer/kivy_hello_world/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/kivy_hello_world/build.xml
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    -set-mode-check:
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    -set-debug-files:
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    -check-env:
[DEBUG]:     [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.6.2
[DEBUG]:     [checkenv] Installed at /home/buildozer/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    -setup:
[DEBUG]:         [echo] Project Name: HelloWorld-0.1
[DEBUG]:      [gettype] Project Type: Application
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    -set-debug-mode:
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    -debug-obfuscation-check:
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    -pre-build:
[DEBUG]:         [copy] Copying 25 files to /home/buildozer/kivy_hello_world/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/kivy_hello_world/tmp-src
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    -build-setup:
[DEBUG]:    [getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.1.0
[DEBUG]:         [echo] Resolving Build Target for HelloWorld-0.1...
[DEBUG]:    [gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
[DEBUG]:    [gettarget] API level:        19
[DEBUG]:         [echo] ----------
[DEBUG]:         [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
[DEBUG]:        [mkdir] Created dir: /home/buildozer/kivy_hello_world/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/kivy_hello_world/bin/rsObj
[DEBUG]:        [mkdir] Created dir: /home/buildozer/kivy_hello_world/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/kivy_hello_world/bin/rsLibs
[DEBUG]:         [echo] ----------
[DEBUG]:         [echo] Resolving Dependencies for HelloWorld-0.1...
[DEBUG]:    [dependency] Library dependencies:
[DEBUG]:    [dependency] No Libraries
[DEBUG]:    [dependency]
[DEBUG]:    [dependency] ------------------
[DEBUG]:         [echo] ----------
[DEBUG]:         [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...
[DEBUG]:       [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    -code-gen:
[DEBUG]:    [mergemanifest] Found modified input file
[DEBUG]:    [mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[DEBUG]:    [mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
[DEBUG]:         [echo] Handling aidl files...
[DEBUG]:         [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
[DEBUG]:         [echo] ----------
[DEBUG]:         [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
[DEBUG]:         [echo] ----------
[DEBUG]:         [echo] Handling Resources...
[DEBUG]:         [aapt] Found new input file
[DEBUG]:         [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
[DEBUG]:         [aapt]     (skipping file '.gitkeep' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
[DEBUG]:         [echo] ----------
[DEBUG]:         [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[DEBUG]:    [buildconfig] No need to generate new BuildConfig.
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    -pre-compile:
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    -compile:
[DEBUG]:        [javac] Compiling 25 source files to /home/buildozer/kivy_hello_world/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/kivy_hello_world/bin/classes
[DEBUG]:        [javac] warning: [options] source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
[DEBUG]:        [javac] warning: [options] target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
[DEBUG]:        [javac] warning: [options] To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
[DEBUG]:        [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[DEBUG]:        [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[DEBUG]:        [javac] 3 warnings
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    -post-compile:
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    -obfuscate:
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    -dex:
[DEBUG]:          [dex] input: /home/buildozer/kivy_hello_world/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/kivy_hello_world/bin/classes
[DEBUG]:          [dex] Found modified input file
[DEBUG]:          [dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into /home/buildozer/kivy_hello_world/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/kivy_hello_world/bin/classes.dex...
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    -crunch:
[DEBUG]:       [crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: /home/buildozer/kivy_hello_world/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/kivy_hello_world/src/main/res
[DEBUG]:       [crunch] To destination dir: /home/buildozer/kivy_hello_world/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/kivy_hello_world/bin/res
[DEBUG]:       [crunch] Processing image to cache: /home/buildozer/kivy_hello_world/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/kivy_hello_world/src/main/res/drawable/icon.png => /home/buildozer/kivy_hello_world/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/kivy_hello_world/bin/res/drawable/icon.png
[DEBUG]:       [crunch]   (processed image to cache entry /home/buildozer/kivy_hello_world/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/kivy_hello_world/bin/res/drawable/icon.png: 126% size of source)
[DEBUG]:       [crunch] Crunched 1 PNG files to update cache
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    -package-resources:
[DEBUG]:         [aapt] Found modified input file
[DEBUG]:         [aapt] Creating full resource package...
[DEBUG]:         [aapt]     (skipping file '.gitkeep' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
[DEBUG]:         [aapt]     (skipping file '.gitkeep' due to ANDROID_AAPT_IGNORE pattern '.*')
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    -package:
[DEBUG]:    [apkbuilder] Found modified input file
[DEBUG]:    [apkbuilder] Creating HelloWorld-0.1-debug-unaligned.apk and signing it with a debug key...
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    -post-package:
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    -do-debug:
[DEBUG]:     [zipalign] Running zip align on final apk...
[DEBUG]:         [echo] Debug Package: /home/buildozer/kivy_hello_world/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/kivy_hello_world/bin/HelloWorld-0.1-debug.apk
[DEBUG]:    [propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/buildozer/kivy_hello_world/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/kivy_hello_world/bin/build.prop
[DEBUG]:    [propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/buildozer/kivy_hello_world/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/kivy_hello_world/bin/build.prop
[DEBUG]:    [propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/buildozer/kivy_hello_world/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/kivy_hello_world/bin/build.prop
[DEBUG]:    [propertyfile] Updating property file: /home/buildozer/kivy_hello_world/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/kivy_hello_world/bin/build.prop
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    -post-build:
[DEBUG]:       [delete] Deleting directory /home/buildozer/kivy_hello_world/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/kivy_hello_world/tmp-src
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    debug:
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:    BUILD SUCCESSFUL
[DEBUG]:    Total time: 12 seconds
[INFO]:    <- directory context /home/buildozer/kivy_hello_world/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android-new-toolchain
[INFO]:    # Copying APK to current directory
[INFO]:    # Found APK file: /home/buildozer/kivy_hello_world/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/kivy_hello_world/bin/HelloWorld-0.1-debug.apk
[DEBUG]:   -> running cp /home/buildozer/kivy_hello_world/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/kivy_hello_world/bin/HelloWorld-0.1-debug.apk ./
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 1058, in run_command
    self.target.run_commands(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 92, in run_commands
    func(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 104, in cmd_debug
    self.buildozer.build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 212, in build
    self.target.build_package()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 817, in build_package
    copyfile(join(apk_dir, apk), join(self.buildozer.bin_dir, apk_dest))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 96, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/home/buildozer/kivy_hello_world/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/kivy_hello_world/build/outputs/apk/kivy_hello_world-debug.apk'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in buildozer's apk copying, you can probably find the apk in `/home/buildozer/kivy_hello_world/.buildozer/android/platform/build/dists/kivy_hello_world/bin`.

Comment: Thanks, inclement.  Yes, I agree with you.
I use this build env. for beginner for learning so it is difficult to manual copy to fix. My idea to solve; (1) give up, (2) fixed vm on docker for buildozer can copy correctly .apk file (3) I try to fix this bug of buildozer.

The best is (2) i think.